# calculate years compound interest python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i have this task, i need to create formula in python, I have all the program running good, but i just can't think of the formula to count years, that's compound interest

what i need to count is how many years will it take to get to the target(lets say from 1500 to 2000)

Got this formula t = ln(A/P) / n[ln(1 + r/n)], but i don't get the right answer
https://www.thecalculatorsite.com/articles/finance/compound-interest-formula.php

Also tried this
https://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/logarithm/logarithm.faq.question.117944.html

update.
Thanks for help! answer in comments for those who have same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work:

```
from math import log

p_start = 1500 # Beginning principal
r = 4.3 # Interest rate
p_end = 2000 # Ending principal

"""
# Lambda function
# n == number of compounding periods per year.
    # Default n is 12, or monthly compounding

# Formula Breakdown
round((
       log(A / P) /
       (n * (
               log(1 + (r/n))
               )
        )
    # Add 0.5 to account for needing to round up.
    ) + 0.5
# Round to zero decimal places
, 0)
"""
get_time = lambda A, P, r, n=12: round((log(A / P) / (n * (log(1 + (r/n))))) + 0.5, 0)

# If interest rate isn't a percentage, convert it
if r > 0:
    r /= 100

get_time(p_end, p_start, r, 1) # 7.0 using n = 1, or compounded once per year.
```

---

EDIT: Adding solution for comment below:

```
def calculate_years_to_target(principal, rate, target, n=12):

    if rate > 0:
        rate /= 100

    years = round((math.log(target / principal) / (n * (math.log(1 + (rate/n))))) + 0.5, 0)
    return years


calculate_years_to_target(1500, 4.3, 2000, 1)
```

Comment: `def calculate_years_to_target(principal, rate, target):
    years = lambda principal, target, rate, n=12: round((math.log(target / principal) / (n * (math.log(1 + (rate/n))))) + 0.5, 0)
    return years`   error i get: <function calculate_years_to_target.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f96e438fe50>

Comment: Okay, I added your function in an edit.  The lambda acts like an "anonymous" function, so you didn't need it inside you function.  (It's weird, I know.)  Otherwise, it looked good!

Comment: Thanks so much! Love you!

Answer (score 0):

Compound Interest Calculator:

```
import math

P = float(input("Enter the initial deposit: "))
A = float(input("Enter the final amount: "))
N = float(input("Enter the number of times the interest is applied per time period: "))
T = float(input("Enter the number of time periods elapsed: "))

interestRate = N*(pow(A/P, 1/(N*T))-1)*100
print("The interest rate is " + str(interestRate) + "%.")
```

Comment: that's not what i need, i need to count T(years) i already have interest rate